# AWS CDK Custom Domain for Private API Gateway Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Trying to associate a custom domain name (ie `api.internal.domain.com`) in a private hosted zone to a private API gateway deployment using CDK. Here's what I have so far.

```
PRIVATE_HOSTED_ZONE_NAME=internal.domain.com
PRIVATE_HOSTED_ZONE_ID=xxxxxxx
API_HOST_RECORD=api
FULL_DNS_RECORD_NAME = `${API_HOST_RECORD}.${PRIVATE_HOSTED_ZONE_NAME}`
```

```
// get the private hosted zone for internal.domain.com
const privateHostedZone = route53.PrivateHostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'PrivateHostedZone', {
  zoneName: PRIVATE_HOSTED_ZONE_NAME,
  hostedZoneId: PRIVATE_HOSTED_ZONE_ID,
});

// get the cert for *.internal.domain.com
const certificate = acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'Certificate', `${process.env.API_SSL_CERTIFICATE_ARN}`);

// create a VPC endpoint for API gateway
const restApiVpcEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, 'RestApiVpcEndpoint', {
  vpc,
  privateDnsEnabled: true,
  subnets: vpc.selectSubnets({
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE,
  }),
  service: {
    name: 'com.amazonaws.us-east-1.execute-api',
    port: 443,
  },
});

// custom resource to retrieve ENI IPs for NLB
// https://repost.aws/questions/QUjISNyk6aTA6jZgZQwKWf4Q/how-to-connect-a-load-balancer-and-an-interface-vpc-endpoint-together-using-cdk
const eni = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'DescribeNetworkInterfaces', {
  onCreate: {
    service: 'EC2',
    action: 'describeNetworkInterfaces',
    parameters: {
      NetworkInterfaceIds: restApiVpcEndpoint.vpcEndpointNetworkInterfaceIds,
    },
    physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
  },
  onUpdate: {
    service: 'EC2',
    action: 'describeNetworkInterfaces',
    parameters: {
      NetworkInterfaceIds: restApiVpcEndpoint.vpcEndpointNetworkInterfaceIds,
    },
    physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
  },
  policy: {
    statements: [
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ['ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'],
        resources: ['*'],
      }),
    ],
  },
});

// create API Gateway
const restApiGateway = new apigateway.LambdaRestApi(this, 'RestApiGateway', {
  handler: apiLambda,
  proxy: false,
  endpointConfiguration: {
    types: [apigateway.EndpointType.PRIVATE],
    vpcEndpoints: [restApiVpcEndpoint],
  },
  domainName: {
    domainName: FULL_DNS_RECORD_NAME,
    certificate: certificate,
  },
  policy: new iam.PolicyDocument({
    statements: [
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        actions: ['execute-api:Invoke'],
        resources: ['execute-api:/*'],
        effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
        conditions: {
          StringNotEquals: {
            'aws:SourceVpce': restApiVpcEndpoint.vpcEndpointId,
          },
        },
      }),
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        actions: ['execute-api:Invoke'],
        resources: ['execute-api:/*'],
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      }),
    ],
  }),

  deployOptions: {
    dataTraceEnabled: true,
    tracingEnabled: true,
  },
});


// workaround for private api gateway with custom domain
const lb = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'LB', {
  vpc: vpc,
  internetFacing: false,
});

const lbHttpsListener = lb.addListener('lbListener', {
  port: 443,
  certificates: [certificate],
});

const ip1 = eni.getResponseField('NetworkInterfaces.0.PrivateIpAddress');
const ip2 = eni.getResponseField('NetworkInterfaces.1.PrivateIpAddress');

lbHttpsListener.addTargets('Target', {
  port: 443,
  targets: [new albTargets.IpTarget(ip1), new albTargets.IpTarget(ip2)],
});

new route53.ARecord(this, 'CustomDomainAliasRecord', {
  zone: privateHostedZone,
  recordName: API_HOST_RECORD,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.LoadBalancerTarget(lb)),
});
```

After deployment, I can successfully curl directly to the API Gateway from an EC2 instance in the same VPC. I can also resolve the custom DNS host (`api.internal.domain.com`).

But when I curl `api.internal.domain.com`, I get a `504 Gateway Time-out`. Starting from Route53, the alias to the load balancer is configured correctly. The load balancer targets have the correct IP addresses but all health check is `Unhealthy`.

[image]

Also, when I curl the IPs directly (`curl -v -k https://10.0.176.185`), I get the following response.

```
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: Server
< Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2022 02:16:23 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 23
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: aeda494b-a60d-4a42-be14-816e8ff93aa0
< x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
< x-amz-apigw-id: TRx6xEYxxxxx    // also strange, no know what apigw id this is?
< 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection #0 to host 10.0.176.185 left intact
{"message":"Forbidden"}
```

I tried using different headers, setting API keys and usage plans, messing with the resource policy, changing the health check to allow 200-499. Nothing seems to work. Hoping someone dealt with this issue before.

I have a strong suspicion that something is not right between the VPC endpoint and Private API gateway, but can't find any solutions.

References:

- https://gist.github.com/skorfmann/6941326b2dd75f52cb67e1853c5f8601
- https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-samples/tree/main/apigw-private-custom-domain-name
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html